# Variable that stores its value even you close the file and restart the computer?

Tags: python, file, variables, global-variables

As the title says.

Is there a way to make a variable in python that "stays" even you close the file and even restart the computer? I also need to be able to access that variable anytime in the program.

The way im thinking of doing this is by making a txt file and then putting the value of the variable there, but I think its inefficient because I would need to always open the file. Moreover if the file gets deleted, then I also lost the value of that variable.

Here is some pseudocode of what I am thinking to do.

```
if the file does not exists:
    file = open('file.txt','w')
    x = 1
    file.write(x)

if the file exists:
    file = open('file.txt','r')
    x = file.read()

    <do stuff with the variable x>


file.close()
```

I want something that I can just instantly access.

P.S. I am planning to convert my python script to a .exe file using pyinstaller, hence I need the code to work even the file has been converted to .exe.

Comment: Saving to file is how this would be done. Opening a single file is quite cheap, so I wouldn't worry about how "inefficient" it is.

Comment: Why not use environment variables and save it in .bashrc file ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi can you help me to do that? i am not that good in systems yet.

Comment: There are many ways to do this and most, if not all, will involve doing file I/O. Look up variable (or object) "persistence".

Comment: all programs use some type of file to keep data between running. It can be .txt, .cfg, .xml, .json or even file with database SQLite (ie. Chrome/Firefox use SQLite to keep bookmarks and history of all visited pages). In Python you can also use `pickle` to easily keep it in file. And in all programs you can accidently delete file and lost data - but you can create backup file or you should use external  backup for all files in system.

Comment: if you plan to use it with `pyinstaller` then you should read how to keep files with data because pyinstaller created self-extracted .zip file with your script and Python - and when you run .exe then it create temporary folder, extract files and run it. But when you close program then it deletes folder with all files (and next time it creates this folder again). You would have to keep saved data in separated folder.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you want to convert it to a .exe file, so I assume that you are using windows, maybe a good option can be store in Windows regedit. Take a look in the thread [How to store variables/preferences in Python for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644183/how-to-store-variables-preferences-in-python-for-later-use) that I think that will help you

Comment: Although, depending on the registry hive you're adding to, the data may be written to the disk anyways iirc.